# How to load a bitmap on a window on PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I currently have a PIL Image that I'd like to display on a PyQt window. I know this must be easy, but I can't find anywhere how to do it. Could anyone give me a hand on this?
Here is the code of the window I currently have:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Window')


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Edit: According to Rapid Gui Programming with Qt and Python:

> According to PyQt’s documentation,
>   QPixmaps are optimized for on-screen
>   display (so they are fast to draw),
>   and QImages are optimized for editing
>   (which is why we have used them to
>   hold the image data).

I have a complex algorithm that will generate pictures I want to show on my window. They will be created pretty fast, so to the user they will look just like an animation (there can be like 15+, 20+ of them per second). Should I then use QPixmaps or QImages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this, you can use http://svn.effbot.org/public/stuff/sandbox/pil/ImageQt.py to convert any pil image to qimage

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PIL import Image

def get_pil_image(w, h):
    clr = chr(0)+chr(255)+chr(0)
    im = Image.fromstring("RGB", (w,h), clr*(w*h))
    return im

def pil2qpixmap(pil_image):
    w, h = pil_image.size
    data = pil_image.tostring("raw", "BGRX")
    qimage = QtGui.QImage(data, w, h, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
    qpixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(w,h)
    pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qimage)
    return pix

class ImageLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QLabel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Window')

        self.pix = pil2qpixmap(get_pil_image(50,50))
        self.setPixmap(self.pix)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
imageLabel = ImageLabel()
imageLabel.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: just a nit pick but shouldn't your instantiation start with a lower case letter `imageLabel`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarging to [this discussion](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2005-02/thread00600-0.html), the fastest way would be to use GLPainter in order to benefit of the Graphic Card performance.